# multiline html textarea

Tags: html, forms, input, textarea

My form inherits several css styles, and the default display for a textarea only has a single row-- if you type a paragraph it won't wrap but continues going one the same line. How do I force it back to multi-row output? I have set the "rows" and "cols" attributes in the HTML but it doesn't seem to do anything.

The HTML is highly nested, but the actual input element is:

```
<input name="input47" type="textarea" rows="3" cols="10" />
```

The CSS I've tried is:

```
body form ol.sections li ol.prompts li ol.entries li ol.inputs li input[type=textarea] {
  height: 500px !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

The 500px works regardless whether or not I use `!important`, but there is only a single line of text in the textarea, vertically centered (Chrome and Safari).

EDIT: Clearly I need to brush up on my HTML-- `<input type="textarea">` should have been `<textarea>`

Comment: are you wanting to dynamically change it back with javascript or another client side scripting language?

Comment: It's hard to reproduce without the real example

Comment: A [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) would really help. Can you please add the CSS and HTML that you are having a problem with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You misuse `<input />` element here. What you want to get is

```html
<textarea name="input47" rows="3" cols="10">
        Your multiline text is here.
    </textarea>
```

Comment: Ha. Oops. Just figured that out myself.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have something like

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

applied to your textarea somewhere in your stylesheet and that's what makes it render the whole chunk of text in one line.

Just add something like

```
textarea#myfield {
    white-space: normal
}
```

There should be no need for `!important` in the style above, but if you don't get the result, you can try `!important`

Comment: I have added another answer since the issue is completely different after you have added the example

Comment: I had same issue. By white-space: normal too it is not getting into multiline.

Answer (score 1):

please be aware that except of rows and cols you might also set height and width, which would affect it. It might be the case that you sets rows, but css property height overwrites it.

Comment: it doesn't seem to matter-- just tried setting height to 500px and there's still one single row of text centered vertically

Comment: did you try to add !important ? like height: 500px !important;
what browser do you use?
Could you provide a link to the problem? or at least copy-paste html structure and relevant css?

Answer (score -4):

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameFSM : MonoBehaviour {
    public enum {LevelAwal, diam, terbang/lompat, objek, pertanyaan, bintang, menembak, 
        menghindar, enemy, nyawa, GameOver, NextLevel}

```
public TurnStates state;
public bool gameInProgress = true;

void Start () {
    state = GameFSM.Mulai.Init;
    StartCoroutine ("TurnFSM");
}
private IEnumerator TurnFSM (){
    while(gameInProgress){
        switch(state){
        case TurnStates.LevelAwal:
            if( Permainan Awal()) {* state = diam:}
            break;
        case TurnStates.diam:
            if(Mulai()) {* state =lompat/terbang;}
            break;
        case TurnStates.Jump:
            if( Melompat()) {* state = objek;}
            break;
        case TurnStates.benda:
            if( mencari objek()) {* state = pertanyaan;}
            if (menghindar ()) {* state = enemy;}
            break;
        case TurnStates.objek:
            if( mencari Benda ()) {* state = pertanyaan;}
            if(Menembak()) {* state = enemy;}
            break;
        case TurnStates.enemy:
            if( Terkena Enemy ()) {* state = nyawa;}
            Break;
        case TurnStates.soal:
            if( benar ()) {* state = k;}
            else (salah ()) {* state = nyawa;}
            break;
        case TurnStates.nyawa:
            if(nyawa masih tersedia ()) {* state = diam;}
            else (nyawa masih habis ()) {* state = GameOver;}
            Break;
        case TurnStates.Kunci:
            if( berhasil menjawab()) {*state = NextGame;}
            break;
        case TurnState.NextGame :
            if (DoneLevel ()) {* state = LevelBaru;}
            break;
        }
        yield return null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I suggest adding a bit of explanation to accompany your code. Also, please ensure all of your code is wrapped in StackOverflow code formatting for readability.